# Passing Correlated/Parametrized value with in another Correlated value in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I want to save correlated variable locally then i might need to put that variable with in another correlated value and then i should send it to subsequent request in Jmeter. Please suggest me a way to perform the same.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please add the relevant context.

Comment: Check this article about how to save extract value. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor 

Assume that you are saving a variable paramid, you can use that anywhere in the test plan using ${paramid}. To concatenate, you can use ${paramid}${myanotherparamid} and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V), as per the documentation:

> For example, if one has variables **A1,A2** and **N=1**:
>
> **${A1}** - works OK
>
> **${A${N}}** - does not work (nested variable reference)
>
> **${__V(A${N})}** - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

Also in some cases you can use [__evalVar() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar).

Going forward you need to be more specific so we could come up with the exact solution, in the meantime check out [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article.